# entity framework many to many still execting foreign key after fluent api

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

I've created an entity framework m:m relationship between the user identity class and another class called group.

Although I've given both classes an ICollection property linking to the other one, it didn't automatically create the many to many table and I've instead created it with fluent API -  GroupUsers table. All appears to be ok.

When I try to register a user, it fails. From looking at the SQL generated it appears to be expecting the Group_Id field to be present in the Users table - not sure why it's looking for this as it is now in a separate table.

The group class (entity just has an id property)

```
public class Group : Entity
{
    public Group()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

The user class (customised the application user class)

```
    public class User : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Groups = new HashSet<Group>();
    }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<User, int> manager, string authenticationType)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

As you can see above both have a property relationship with the other class.

Fluent API:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(u => u.Groups).WithMany(g => g.Users).Map(x =>
        {
            x.MapLeftKey("GroupId");
            x.MapRightKey("UserId");
            x.ToTable("GroupUsers");
        });
```

All the above creates the tables: User, Group, and GroupUsers.

I would have expected this to be working as it is.

Unfortunately, when I try to register a user it still looks to be expecting the Group_Id to be present in the User table:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Limit1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Limit1].[Firstname] AS [Firstname], 
[Limit1].[Lastname] AS [Lastname],  
[Limit1].[Email] AS [Email], 
[Limit1].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
[Limit1].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
[Limit1].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
[Limit1].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
[Limit1].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
[Limit1].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
[Limit1].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
[Limit1].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
[Limit1].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
[Limit1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
[Limit1].[Group_Id] AS [Group_Id] ---why is this here??
FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Firstname] AS [Firstname], 
    [Extent1].[Lastname] AS [Lastname], 
    [Extent1].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Extent1].[EmailConfirmed] AS [EmailConfirmed], 
    [Extent1].[PasswordHash] AS [PasswordHash], 
    [Extent1].[SecurityStamp] AS [SecurityStamp], 
    [Extent1].[PhoneNumber] AS [PhoneNumber], 
    [Extent1].[PhoneNumberConfirmed] AS [PhoneNumberConfirmed], 
    [Extent1].[TwoFactorEnabled] AS [TwoFactorEnabled], 
    [Extent1].[LockoutEndDateUtc] AS [LockoutEndDateUtc], 
    [Extent1].[LockoutEnabled] AS [LockoutEnabled], 
    [Extent1].[AccessFailedCount] AS [AccessFailedCount], 
    [Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName], 
    [Extent1].[Group_Id] AS [Group_Id]
    FROM [dbo].[AspNetUsers] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ((UPPER([Extent1].[UserName])) = (UPPER(@p__linq__0))) OR ((UPPER([Extent1].[UserName]) IS NULL) AND (UPPER(@p__linq__0) IS NULL))
)  AS [Limit1]',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'myemail@myemail.com'
```

When I run the SQL seperately, I just get :

Invalid column name 'Group_Id'.

Any ideas why it's not working correctly and why group_id is expected to be there, even though it's specified in the fluent API that it shouldn't be?

Thanks,

Comment: Actually, I believe you want `x.MapLeftKey("UserId");` since that is the parent table. Yeah - that would cause EF to create Group_Id since it can't find GroupId in the UserTable. Flip the left/right definitions.

Comment: Nice try..but does not appear to have solved the prob. I've tried both FKs in that table with and without underscores, flipped them like you said and tried it without any mapping (yep user_id was on left, group_id on right). No change..still looking for Group_Id. Absolute mystery.

Comment: So database User table has Group_Id field? How are you updating the database? Migrations or initializer?

Comment: Migrations. User table does not have a Group_Id field which is correct. The User_Id and Group_Id will be stored their own table. The SQL is excepting the Group_Id to be in the user table. It appears to be searching for the user prior when registering...but it's excepting a Group_Id to be in the User table. It doesn't appear to have picked up that there's a many to many relationships going on with a separate table...

Comment: Case like this I usually change the connect string to point to a new database and see what EF does. Or you could generate a script `update-database -Script -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase`.